# Nautilus and Terminal icons not displaying on metacity desktop

Tags: gnome, nautilus, icons, metacity

I am using metacity from gnome-flashback. For some reason, icons for most of the programs I use (e.g., `firefox.desktop`, `steam.desktop`, `gedit.desktop`) reliably appear on the desktop. However, icons for the two items in my desktop directory:

```
org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
gnome-terminal.desktop
```

do not appear. I can open nautilus, go to `~/Desktop` and manually drag the icons onto the desktop and they will appear. However, when I log out and log back in, the desktop icons are gone. The desktop icons do appear on the desktop when I log in to unity.

How do I get these icons to appear on the desktop and stay there?

Comment: Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Comment: Can you post content of these two files that does not work?

Comment: That was a good idea. The problem was both those files had a line ``OnlyShowIn=Unity;`` which I comment out. Now they appear correctly on the metacity desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following muktupavels request to show the content, the problem was the content of

```
org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
gnome-terminal.desktop
```

contained a line `OnlyShowIn=Unity;` when this line is commented out, the icons display correctly on the metacity desktop.